# How to eliminate the conditional in my accumulator?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

Given this code:

```cs
private static IObservable<Stock> ToStock(this IObservable<decimal> prices, string symbol)
{
    return prices.Scan(
        default(Stock),
        (previous, price) => previous == default(Stock)
            ? new Stock(symbol, price)
            : previous.Change(price));
}

// The signature for Stock.Change() looks like this. Stock is an immutable class.
// public Stock Change(decimal newCurrentPrice)
```

I would like to eliminate the check `previous == default(Stock)` that is happening on every call to the accumulator. What I have is behavior that is different for the first item vs the rest. I'm not sure how to express that simply using LINQ for Rx.

EDIT. Here's the code for Stock, which might help explain why I can't give it a sentinel value for price.

```
public class Stock
{
    private readonly decimal _current;
    private readonly decimal _dayHigh;
    private readonly decimal _dayLow;
    private readonly decimal _dayOpen;
    private readonly decimal _lastChange;
    private readonly string _symbol;

    public Stock(string symbol, decimal price)
    {
        if (symbol == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("symbol");
        if (price <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("price", "Price must be greater than zero.");

        _symbol = symbol;
        _current = _dayOpen = _dayLow = _dayHigh = price;
    }

    private Stock(Stock original, decimal newCurrent)
    {
        if (original == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("original");

        _symbol = original.Symbol;
        _current = newCurrent;
        _dayOpen = original.DayOpen;
        _dayHigh = Math.Max(newCurrent, original.DayHigh);
        _dayLow = Math.Min(newCurrent, original.DayLow);
        _lastChange = newCurrent - original.Current;
    }

    public string Symbol { get { return _symbol; } }
    public decimal Current { get { return _current; } }
    public decimal LastChange { get { return _lastChange; } }
    public decimal DayOpen { get { return _dayOpen; } }
    public decimal DayLow { get { return _dayLow; } }
    public decimal DayHigh { get { return _dayHigh; } }
    public decimal DayChange { get { return Current - DayOpen; } }
    public double DayChangeRatio { get { return (double) Math.Round(DayChange/Current, 4); } }

    public Stock Change(decimal newCurrent)
    {
        return newCurrent == Current
            ? this
            : new Stock(this, newCurrent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? For what reason, there may be a better solution.

Comment: Performance and/or cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
private static IObservable<Stock> ToStock2(this IObservable<decimal> prices, string symbol)
{
    Func<Stock, decimal, Stock> accumulator = (_, firstPrice) =>
    {
        accumulator = (previous, price) => previous.Change(price);
        return new Stock(symbol, firstPrice);
    };

    return prices.Scan(default(Stock), (previous, price) => accumulator(previous, price));
}
```

It uses a self-mutating `Func` variable to change the behavior during its first invocation, but a quick test (ran with 0.5 million prices) shows that it performs 2-3% slower than the original method, and the code is much less clear. It seems .NET is more efficient at doing the equality comparer for every item, vs. calling a second `Func` for every item. I'm not sure if there's anyway to optimize this so that it performs better enough than the original to justify the lessened clarity.

Comment: It could be your processor and not the compiler. Branch-prediction could guess that you're not going down one branch anymore on your == version.

Comment: Mutation of accumulator function is not clear solution. Your problem is the null seed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public static partial class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<Stock> ToStock(this IObservable<decimal> prices, string symbol)
    {                                                
        return Observable.Create<Stock>(o =>
        {
            Stock lastStock;            
            Action<decimal> action = null;
            action = price => {
                lastStock = new Stock(symbol, price);
                action = newPrice =>
                    {
                        lastStock = lastStock.Change(newPrice);
                        o.OnNext(lastStock);
                    };
                o.OnNext(lastStock);
            };

            return prices.Subscribe(p => action(p), o.OnError, o.OnCompleted);
        });    
    }   
}
```

Compared to Jim's answer, I'm not sure if mine is any better; it's a similar idea but it avoids calling Scan which may avoid some hops.

My flakey performance tests showed this runs no worse than the original - but no better either. I ran it a few times with 100,000,000 prices and they took within 1% of each other with each winning roughly half the time. There was no statistically significant difference.

I would take this with a pinch of salt though, as this is on my home PC and not in a lab environment, not run for very long and with god knows what other services installed.

HOWEVER... I did get a seemly significant 3% improvement by rewriting the private constructor to not do the `Math.Max/Min` calculation redundantly, and to bypass the properties and access the fields directly - and I'm sure there's further mileage to be explored such as removing `Change` and using public fields:

```
private Stock(Stock original, decimal newCurrent)
{
    if (original == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("original");

    _symbol = original._symbol;
    _current = newCurrent;
    _dayOpen = original._dayOpen;        
    if(newCurrent > original._dayHigh)
    {
        _dayHigh = newCurrent;
        _dayLow = original._dayLow;            
    }
    else
    {
        _dayHigh = original._dayHigh;
        _dayLow = newCurrent;          
    }
    _lastChange = newCurrent - original._current;
}
```

On general performance - with a lot of prices, there is going to be a fair amount of GC pressure with this approach. I've had success in the past with using a pool of Stock instances in a ring buffer implemented with an array to reduce garbage collection.

Comment: Perhaps you can run your performance test on it for me Jim? ;)

Comment: Also, don't try to replace the final lambda with a method group, or you'll break it! :)

Comment: Added some perf testing notes.

Comment: Why the downvote? Interested to hear the thinking here!

Comment: This is good stuff. I imagine your expanded function is similar to what Scan is doing. I might go check the source to see how it compares. Unfortunately this is still way less clear than the original with no worthy perf gains, so the original still is leading.

Comment: Agreed. And Aleš's point about the general performance of Rx is well made.

Answer (score 0):

```
return prices.Skip(1)
             .Scan(new Stock(symbol, prices.First()),
               (previous, price) => previous.Change(price));
```

Does this fix your problem of side-effects?

Comment: There's side effects to this, such that if `prices` is not multicast observable (and in my case it's not) then this is effectively creating two separate subscriptions which would iterate the source data twice. The call to `First` is called immediately at the callsite which creates a sub and gets a value while as the rest of the call is delayed until a subscription is made.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to introduce some kind of polymorfism. You can introduce special case of Stock just for seed purpose:

```
public class Stock {

  // same implementation as yours but make the Change method virtual

  public static Stock Seed(string symbol) {
    return new StockSeed(symbol);
  }

  class StockSeed : Stock {
    public StockSeed(string symbol) {
      _symbol = symbol;
    }

    public override Stock Change(decimal newCurrent) {
      return new Stock(Symbol, newCurrent)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can simplify the reactive code to:

```
static IObservable<Stock> ToStock(this IObservable<decimal> prices, string symbol)
{
    return prices.Scan(Stock.Seed(symbol), (prev, price) => prev.Change(price));
}
```

Comment: I really don't belive that virtual method call is issue here. Have you ever seen how are Rx implemented?

Comment: Actually, I have read the source code in some detail many times - although admittedly not looked at Scan recently. I'm not sure what your point is though? Have you performance tested your code? I think speculation is pointless here, and I am genuinely interested in the impact versus the other approaches. I'll run it myself later otherwise, just a bit busy at the moment.

Comment: My first comment was oddly deleted (I'm pretty sure it didn't need moderation!) - just to keep the thread I said the virtual method call *feels* not very different to the mutated delegate from a performance perspective, and I think the total complexity remains the same. Only benchmarking will tell!

Comment: So you know the overhead of Rx implementation, why are you bothered with one virtual method call? It is year 2014, there are other thinks to worry about. I worry more about clean and correct code than what is the cost of one virtual call inside of complex object system.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right about the overhead - and I think I make a similar point elsewhere. My observation is that it's a matter of opinion whether your code is clearer. With your solution, one has to look in two places to understand the purpose of the Seed. The solution is pretty much equivalent to the mutation in that a mutating handler and virtual method call solve the problem in the same way. Maybe some might find the simpler code in two places is as hard to grok as the more complex code that keeps everything relevant to the problem in one place. There's no black and white here.

Comment: Also, given the lack of improvement I've seen currently, I think the OP's code is probably fine as it stands - it's the simplest of all thus far.

Comment: This is effectively the OOP version of the functional version that I had come up with; basically swapping the behavior after the first execution. I think which is clearer is subjective based on one's comfort levels with OOP vs. FP. As far as optimizations are concerned, you're right that these attempts at optimization are insignificant, but this is for the sake of thought exercise and honing one's skills. This is code in a demo project that I'm using to learn Rx that I intend to share with my team once I can speak intelligently on it.

Comment: Nice to see you want to educate your team. Please, don't show them that they can seed a null value (default(Stock)) or mutate lambdas and introduce state. It is not functional at all. :) Good luck.

Comment: I disagree with the null seed part, since the alternative is modifying my domain model so that it can be constructed in an invalid state, which IMHO is a million times worse.

Comment: It is special case and is encapsulated into one function that can be well documented. IMO better than branching because of null all the time.